# Downloading files from a simple HTTP server implemented via Python

Tags: python, html

I have a HTTP Server in Python which is able to take and save files sent via POST request. However, now I am trying to download requested files with GET request. Basically, I want to send a GET request with a filename and I want my server to offer me a file to download. How would I do so?

My code so far:

```
class S(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def _set_headers(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()

def _html(self, message):
    """This just generates an HTML document that includes `message`
    in the body. Override, or re-write this do do more interesting stuff.
    """
    content = f"<html><body><h1>{message}</h1></body></html>"
    return content.encode("utf8")  # NOTE: must return a bytes object!

def do_GET(self):
    self._set_headers()
    self.wfile.write(self._html("hi!"))

def do_HEAD(self):
    self._set_headers()

def do_POST(self):
    form = cgi.FieldStorage(
        fp=self.rfile,
        headers=self.headers,
        environ={'REQUEST_METHOD':'POST',
                 'CONTENT_TYPE':self.headers['Content-Type'],
                 })
    filename = form['file'].filename
    data = form['file'].file.read()
    open(filename, "wb").write(data)
    self._set_headers()
    self.wfile.write(self._html("hi!"))
```

Comment: And so you're having problem with sending GET request or server response?

Comment: @Charnel Server accepts GET request, however I want it to respond with a file.

Answer (score 0):

- Instead of writing custom methods for http response and routing
  engines you can use flask a lighwieght framwork that provide routing
  engine and all features and security to the app and this also provide
  necessary things to manage all kind of http requests

https://www.palletsprojects.com/p/flask/

Comment: I tried using Flask but I had troubles making it work. Could you help me if I send you my flask code?

Comment: sure. what is the issue

Comment: I used privnotes as pastecode wasn't working for me somehow. https://privnote.com/bACFXtsH#fAE7d4XKj . The problem is, that when my client sends a POST request with a file, my flask-running server sees the post request, however it doesn't save the file. My client throws exception. When using my HTTP server with the original code (non-flask), POST works without an issue.

Comment: Its because you havent configured flask for cross server request use below code to configure it first install CORS            pip install   Flask-Cors==3.0.8
paste below codes in your main.py or where your app get bootstrapped                             CORS(app, supports_credentials=True,methods=['GET', 'HEAD', 'POST', 'OPTIONS', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE'])

Comment: I installed CORS, imported not however not sure how to implement it in the code. I get NameError: name 'app' is not defined. Could you show it to me in my code how it should be implemented?

Comment: refer my latest answer

Answer (score 0):

Please maintain below structure in your root directory

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
```

main.py

```
from flask_cors import CORS
import os
from app import app



# allowing cross browser request with cors configuration
CORS(app, supports_credentials=True,methods=['GET', 'HEAD', 'POST', 'OPTIONS', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE'])



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.session_type = os.getenv('SESSION_TYPE')

    app.run(debug=os.getenv('DEBUG'), host=os.getenv(
        'SERVER_HOST'), port=os.getenv('SERVER_PORT'))
```

then execute the python main.py it will activate all routes enjoyy!!

Comment: I get exceptions when running main.py. Should it work on it's own or is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: what is the error? please install all dependencies that requires to run flask in your environment

Comment: yup, sorry it does run, however it didn't solve my issue. When sending files via POST request, it still does fail. The flask server returns 404 error. In the flask console, I get 127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2020 17:23:04] "POST /backup/samplefile.zip HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: Oh, I think I understand now. This is my code. app: https://privnote.com/wzFUYbBQ#Bl230GeJk main: https://privnote.com/eTrTKLxD#DFZpkva8y . It throws 405 ERROR when trying to upload files.